# How can I link multiple subnets on one interface?

Tags: networking

I am trying to divide my network, without the use of VLANs.
I want to create the following networks:

- 10.0.0.1/24 - network0
- 10.0.1.1/24 - network1
- 10.0.3.1/24 - network2
- 10.0.4.1/24 - network3

These IPs all belong to one interface, `eth0`.
I want all devices to be able to communicate with each other, but I am unsure on how to achieve this.
Should I set the subnet mask to `255.255.0.0` instead of `255.255.255.0`? Should I masquerade with firewall rules? What is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a /24 subnet then the netmask is /24, literally. (That's 255.255.255.0 in the long format.)

Note that the netmask isn't a property of the interface. It is a property of an *address* configured on that interface, and when you have the same interface be assigned addresses from multiple networks, it is perfectly possible for them to have different netmasks.

Devices which are in different subnets will communicate through a router (gateway). This applies even if they're on the same physical ethernet. The router will have four IP addresses on the same interface – one for each network, all of them configured as /24s.

(If you try to use a /16 or /22 netmask because you want devices in separate subnets to communicate directly without a gateway, then you *don't have* four networks anymore – you just end up with one large /16 network with no separation whatsoever.)

In general, what you're trying to do is already outside "best practices". It will work for IPv4, it will create problems with IPv6, and it only provides some protection but won't help if the devices are possibly attacker-controlled and can just change their IPs.

Masquerading or NAT should not be involved in this. It should never be necessary to use masquerading internally within a network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use larger subnet:

```
10.0.0.1/22
```

as /22 covers the four networks you mention in your question.

Edit: Or should it be /21 (as you list 0, 1, 3 & 4, not 0, 1, 2 & 3)?

Comment: Is it better practice to use this instead of using separate networks and gateways?